# What's the difference between self and Self?

Tags: rust

I haven't come across `Self` in the documentation, only in the source code. The documentation only uses `self`.

Comment: See the docs here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#self-types

Comment: This documentation was moved to: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html#self-types

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`self` when used as first method argument, is a shorthand for `self: Self`. There are also `&self`, which is equivalent to `self: &Self`, and `&mut self`, which is equivalent to `self: &mut Self`.

`Self` in method arguments is *syntactic sugar* for the receiving type of the method (i.e. the type whose `impl` this method is in). This also allows for generic types without too much repetition.

Comment: Comparing this to java, can I think of Self vs self as class vs this?

Answer (score 204):

[`Self`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html#self-types) is the type of the current object. It may appear either in a `trait` or an `impl`, but appears most often in `trait` where it is a stand-in for whatever type will end up implementing the `trait` (which is unknown when defining the `trait`):

```
trait Clone {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self;
}
```

If I then implement `Clone`:

```
impl Clone for MyType {
    // I can use either the concrete type (known here)
    fn clone(&self) -> MyType;

    // Or I can use Self again, it's shorter after all!
    fn clone(&self) -> Self;
}
```

I could also use it in a regular `impl` if I am lazy (it's shorter!):

```
impl MySuperLongType {
    fn new(a: u32) -> Self { ... }
}
```

---

`self` is the name used in a `trait` or an `impl` for the first argument of a method. Using another name is possible, however there is a notable difference:

- if using `self`, the function introduced is a method
- if using any other name, the function introduced is an associated function

In Rust, there is no implicit `this` argument passed to a type's methods: you have to explicitly pass the "current object" as a method parameter. This would result in:

```
impl MyType {
    fn doit(this: &MyType, a: u32) { ... }
}
```

As we have seen, as a shorter form this could also be (still verbose):

```
impl MyType {
    fn doit(this: &Self, a: u32) { ... }
}
```

Which is actually what `&self` boils down to under the covers.

```
impl MyType {
    fn doit(&self, a: u32) { ... }
}
```

Thus the correspondence table:

```
self => self: Self
&self => self: &Self
&mut self => self: &mut Self
```

The way to invoke those functions change, however:

```
impl MyType {
    fn doit(&self, a: u32) {
        // ...
    }
    fn another(this: &Self, a: u32) {
        // ...
    }
}

fn main() {
    let m = MyType;

    // Both can be used as an associated function
    MyType::doit(&m, 1);
    MyType::another(&m, 2);

    // But only `doit` can be used in method position
    m.doit(3);     // OK: `m` is automatically borrowed
    m.another(4);  // ERROR: no method named `another`
}
```

Comment: **It may appear either in a trait or an impl** - can't it appear in "struct"?

Comment: @jawanam: I personally get *error: use of `Self` outside of an impl or trait* if I attempt it. Maybe the restriction is lifted in a more recent version?

Comment: No, it's currently not possible (as of nightly 2015-09-01). Self-referential structs are quite rare, so adding Self-handling in this case was deemed low-priority.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov: Using `self` or not is not purely syntax, as it is the difference between a method and an associated function. For a plain `struct`, calling a method or an associated function is in turn mostly syntax (though sugar isn't that bad). However, things change on traits: specifically, a trait object (used with `fn doit(d: &Display)` for example) can only be formed on object-safe traits, and associated functions are not object safe (a subset of methods is not safe either).

Answer (score 19):

`Self` refers to the current type that implements a trait, `self` on the other hand refers to the instance.

Having `self` as the first parameter is how rust defines methods. It is just a convention that converts a function into a method, much like in python. Functionally, `self` is analogous to `this` in JavaScript.

For those who don't know the difference between a function and a method, methods are functions that are attached to an instance and invoked via that instance.

`Self` is a generic type and that is why it is not allowed in any position that requires a concrete type. This is commonly referred to as [being object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety) in rust docs.

`Self` is also used in method definitions inside an `impl` block so that when you rename the type during a refactoring, you don't have to go through every method and fixed them.

In Rust, `self` is also used in module resolution which refers to the current module. Here, it imports the `io` module:

```rust
use std::io::{self, Read};
```

Comment: Is there any reason why this answer is not correct?  Assuming it's accurate, I prefer it because it's concise, and therefore much easier (for me) to initially understand and remember.

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh It is not incorrect, does not have vote yet.

Comment: Got it. And nice answer edits, they help -- without losing the first-sentence conciseness, which is great. I have up-voted.

Comment: I think this answer is more updated and should be accepted as the response. It's more generic too.