# Why is self is not moved when calling into_iter on a linked list?

Tags: rust

In the book [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/second-into-iter.html), it tries to create an iterator for the list:

```
pub struct IntoIter<T>(List<T>);

impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn into_iter(self) -> IntoIter<T> {
        IntoIter(self)
    }
}
```

Why is `self` not moved? Is the `self` argument is `pub fn into_iter(self)` a reference or value? Is `self` special and does not obey the common rules for moving or borrowing? What's the relationship between the `IntoIter` and `List`?

Comment: The self argument is special, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304595/whats-the-difference-between-self-and-self "self when used as first method argument, is a shorthand for self: Self ... Self in method arguments is syntactic sugar for the receiving type of the method" & https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/method-syntax.html "Methods take a special first parameter, of which there are three variants: self, &self, and &mut self. You can think of this first parameter as being the foo in foo.bar()."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `self` argument is *not* special (in any way that's relevant to this question). The object on which `into_iter` is called *is* moved. Furthermore, in the method, the variable `self` is then moved into the `IntoIter` struct, just as any `x` in this example:

```
fn into_iter_external<T>(x: List<T>) -> IntoIter<T> {
    IntoIter(x)
}
```

Comment: yes, I also found it's moved, but what's meaning of such tuple struct?

Comment: @kingluo It's just... a struct? They're described [in the book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/structs.html#tuple-structs) but they're conceptually the same as any other struct.