# Understanding the 'self' parameter in the context of trait implementations

Tags: rust, traits, self

When implementing a trait, we often use the keyword `self`, a sample is as follows. I want to understand the representation of the many uses of `self` in this code sample.

```
struct Circle {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    radius: f64,
}

trait HasArea {
    fn area(&self) -> f64;          // first self: &self is equivalent to &HasArea
}

impl HasArea for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {         //second self: &self is equivalent to &Circle
        std::f64::consts::PI * (self.radius * self.radius) // third:self
    }
}
```

My understanding is:

1. The first `self`: `&self` is equivalent to `&HasArea`.
2. The second `self`: `&self` is equivalent to `&Circle`.
3. Is the third `self` representing `Circle`? If so, if `self.radius` was used twice, will that cause a move problem?

Additionally, more examples to show the different usage of the `self` keyword in varying context would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may be interested in [What is the difference between `self` and `Self`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304595/whats-the-difference-between-self-and-self).

Comment: The question about `self.radius` is slightly different than the question about itself (it's about ownership and `Copy`). I suggest you edit it out to focus on what `self` is about here since that's the most difficult (and novel) part, whereas we already have plenty of questions about ownership.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're mostly right.

The way I think of it is that in a method signature, `self` is a shorthand:

```
impl S {
    fn foo(self) {}      // equivalent to fn foo(self: S)
    fn foo(&self) {}     // equivalent to fn foo(self: &S)
    fn foo(&mut self) {} // equivalent to fn foo(self: &mut S)
}
```

It's not *actually* equivalent since `self` is a keyword and there are some special rules (for example for lifetime elision), but it's pretty close.

Back to your example:

```
impl HasArea for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {   // like fn area(self: &Circle) -> ... 
        std::f64::consts::PI * (self.radius * self.radius)
    }
}
```

The `self` in the body is of type `&Circle`.  You can't move out of a reference, so `self.radius` can't be a move even once.  In this case `radius` implements `Copy`, so it's just copied out instead of moved.  If it were a more complex type which didn't implement `Copy` then this would be an error.

Comment: So self.radius is like Circle.radius, since radius is f64 so it implement Copy trait. Correct?

Comment: Yes, `self` is a reference to a `Circle`, since it's a method on `Circle`, so `self.radius` is an `f64`.

Answer (score 7):

You are mostly correct.

---

There is a neat trick to let the compiler tell you the type of variables rather than trying to infer them: `let () = ...;`.

Using [the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0f55a50d3e5a298875e9c295c95a8ee2&version=stable&backtrace=0) I get for the 1st case:

```
9 |         let () = self;
  |             ^^ expected &Self, found ()
```

and for the 2nd case:

```
16 |         let () = self;
   |             ^^ expected &Circle, found ()
```

---

The first case is actually special, because `HasArea` is not a type, it's a trait.

So what is `self`? It's nothing *yet*.

Said another way, it poses for *any possible concrete type* that may implement `HasArea`. And thus the only guarantee we have about this trait is that it provides *at least* the interface of `HasArea`.

The key point is that you can place additional bounds. For example you could say:

```
trait HasArea: Debug {
    fn area(&self) -> f64;
}
```

And in this case, `Self: HasArea + Debug`, meaning that `self` provides *both* the interfaces of `HasArea` and `Debug`.

---

The second and third cases are much easier: we know the *exact concrete type* for which the `HasArea` trait is implemented. It's `Circle`.

Therefore, the type of `self` in the `fn area(&self)` method is `&Circle`.

Note that if the type of the parameter is `&Circle` then it follows that in all its uses in the method it is `&Circle`. Rust has static typing (and no flow-dependent typing) so the type of a given binding does not change during its lifetime.

---

Things can get more complicated, however.

Imagine that you have two traits:

```
struct Segment(Point, Point);

impl Segment {
    fn length(&self) -> f64;
}

trait Segmentify {
    fn segmentify(&self) -> Vec<Segment>;
}

trait HasPerimeter {
    fn has_perimeter(&self) -> f64;
}
```

Then, you can implement `HasPerimeter` automatically for all shapes that can be broken down in a sequence of segments.

```
impl<T> HasPerimeter for T
    where T: Segmentify
{
    // Note: there is a "functional" implementation if you prefer
    fn has_perimeter(&self) -> f64 {
        let mut total = 0.0;
        for s in self.segmentify() { total += s.length(); }
        total
    }
}
```

What is the type of `self` here? It's `&T`.

What's `T`? Any type that implements `Segmentify`.

And therefore, all we know about `T` is that it implements `Segmentify` and `HasPerimeter`, and nothing else (we could not use `println("{:?}", self);` because `T` is not guaranteed to implement `Debug`).

Comment: "Note that if the type of the parameter is &Circle then it follows that in all its uses in the method it is &Circle. Rust has static typing (and no flow-dependent typing) so the type of a given binding does not change during its lifetime."   So, self.radius is like &Circle.radius??

Comment: @enaJ: `self.radius` is `f64` yes, which is a `Copy` type.