# Why can't `Self` be used to refer to an enum's variant in a method body?

Tags: enums, rust

This question is now obsolete because this feature has been implemented. [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57741782/4498831).

---

The following Rust code fails to compile:

```
enum Foo {
    Bar,
}

impl Foo {
    fn f() -> Self {
        Self::Bar
    }
}
```

The error message confuses me:

```
error[E0599]: no associated item named `Bar` found for type `Foo` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |         Self::Bar
  |         ^^^^^^^^^
```

The problem can be fixed by using `Foo` instead of `Self`, but this strikes me as strange since `Self` is supposed to refer to the type that is being implemented (ignoring traits), which in this case is `Foo`.

```
enum Foo {
    Bar,
}

impl Foo {
    fn f() -> Self {
        Foo::Bar
    }
}
```

Why can't `Self` be used in this situation? Where exactly can `Self` be used<sup>*</sup>? Is there anything else I can use to avoid repeating the type name in the method body?

<sup><sup>*</sup> I'm ignoring usage in traits, where `Self` refers to whatever type implements the trait.</sup>

Comment: Enums are a bit strange, in that they act in-between types and namespaces. In this case Foo acts more as a namespace. That said, is this just curiosity or is this preventing you to do something you would like to do?

Comment: @PaoloFalabella The common usage of `Self` here is to reduce repetition of the type name. I was just hoping I could have done the same thing in method bodies.

Comment: I came across some good article, https://users.rust-lang.org/t/confused-by-use-of-self-in-example-in-chapter-17-of-rust-book-2nd-edition/11394. Hope it might be of help to you.

Comment: This question is about a previously missing feature that now exists, so it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 6):

An important thing to note is that the error said associated item. `enum Foo { Baz }` doesn't have associated items. A trait can have an associated item:

```
trait FooBaz { type Baz }
//             ^~~~~~~~ - associated item
```

To summarize:

> Why can't `Self` be used in this situation?

Because of [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26264). [RFC 2338](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2338-type-alias-enum-variants.md) has [not been implemented yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49683).

`Self` seems to act as a type alias, albeit with some modifications.

> Where exactly can `Self` be used?

Self can only be used in traits and `impl`s. This code:

```
struct X {
    f: i32,
    x: &Self,
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
error[E0411]: cannot find type `Self` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |     x: &Self,
  |         ^^^^ `Self` is only available in traits and impls
```

This is possibly a temporary situation and might change in the future!

More precisely, `Self` should be used only as part of method signature (e.g. `fn self_in_self_out(&self) -> Self`) or to access an associated type:

```
enum Foo {
    Baz,
}

trait FooBaz {
    type Baz;

    fn b(&self) -> Self::Baz; // Valid use of `Self` as method argument and method output
}


impl FooBaz for Foo {
    type Baz = Foo;

    fn b(&self) -> Self::Baz {
        let x = Foo::Baz as Self::Baz; // You can use associated type, but it's just a type
        x
    }
}
```

I think [user4815162342 covered the rest of the answer best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46407298/155423).

Answer (score 4):

If the enum name `Foo` is in reality long and you want to avoid repeating it across the implementation, you have two options:

- `use LongEnumName as Short` at module level. This will allow you to return `Short::Bar` at the end of `f`.
- `use LongEnumName::*` at module level, allowing an even shorter `Bar`.

If you omit `pub`, the imports will be internal and won't affect the public API of the module.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible as of [version 1.37](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/08/15/Rust-1.37.0.html#referring-to-enum-variants-through-type-aliases).

Answer (score 2):

Enum constructors != associated items.

It is a known [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26264), but it's not expected to be fixed, at least not in the foreseeable future. From what I have gathered it is not trivial to just allow this to work; at this point it is more likely that the related documentation or the error message will be improved.

There is little documentation I could find on the topic of associated items *in general*; The Rust Book has a chapter on [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/associated-types.html), though. In addition, there are plenty of good answers about `Self` in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304595/whats-the-difference-between-self-and-self).

Answer (score 1):

There is an [experimental feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2338-type-alias-enum-variants.md) that would make your example work without any other changes.  You can try it out in a nightly build of Rust by adding this in your main file:

```
#![feature(type_alias_enum_variants)]
```

You can follow the progress of the feature towards stabilisation in its [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49683).