# Why use Self instead of the type's name in a concrete implementation?

Tags: rust, traits, self-type

[The documentation for `Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) gives the following example:

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Add for Point {
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self {
        Self {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}
```

Why did the author of the docs use `Self` here, instead of mentioning `Point` by name? Is there a technical difference, or is it purely for style points?

Comment: Because type names tend to change. Tomorrow you will decide that it is better to be called `Vector`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two main reasons:

- flexibility. If you decide to change the name of your type, it's one less place to update.
- conciseness. `Self` is shorter than `MyType` or `SomeOtherType` and especially `ThisTypeWithGenerics<'a, 'b, A, String>`.

> Is there a technical difference

Yes and no, depending on how you look at it. `Self` is the type that has been "completely filled in" with regards to generics. This is relevant in cases like this:

```
struct Container<T>(T);

impl<T> Container<T> {
    fn replace<U>(self, new: U) -> Self {
        Container(new)
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:5:19
  |
3 | impl<T> Container<T> {
  |      - expected type parameter
4 |     fn replace<U>(self, new: U) -> Self {
  |                - found type parameter
5 |         Container(new)
  |                   ^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found type parameter `U`
  |
  = note: expected type parameter `T`
             found type parameter `U`
  = note: a type parameter was expected, but a different one was found; you might be missing a type parameter or trait bound
  = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

`Self` is the complete type `Container<T>`, *not* the type constructor `Container`. This can cause [hard-to-understand errors](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/68476).

See also:

- [What's the difference between self and Self?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32304595/155423)

Comment: I would add a 3rd reason: human pattern-matching. My brain seem to recognize `self` and `Self` and special-case them, so it's less effort for me than parsing `Point` and think *oh yes, the current type*.